# Cannot launch Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there anyone know how to deal with Spark installation? I tried to install spark on my linux mint but it cannot launch.

I had install java and scala but when I tried to launch my spark, it did not worked. Is there any advice than I can take?

[image: Spark]

[image: Java_Path]

Comment: I suggest you use the binary version https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html - or follow the instructions further down that page if you want to build it (as the error message tells you).

Comment: use the binary or pre-built version or else you need to build it.